# How can I use a variable as the description for a charge in a Twilio pay connector (Stripe)

Tags: twilio

I would like to variable description in a (Stripe) pay widget in Twilio's Studio flow. Usually you can use liquid like `{{widgets.WIDGET_NAME.Digits}}` in `Say` widgets. Is there a way to do this? What can I use the Connector parameters for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I can see, the description field does not support liquid tags.

The Connector Parameters match up to the `<Parameter>` TwiML element that can be used within a `<Pay>` element. According to [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pay#parameter-noun):

> `<Parameter>` is required when accepting ACH payments in order to capture certain ACH information not included as part of the `<Pay>` verb to send to the payment provider. The value(s) that have to be captured by `<Parameter>` depend on the payment provider.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to have a variable description? is this a feature they can add at Twilio?

Comment: Is there a list of custom params available for Stripe connector?